# How to make an empty plane, and add points on the way

Tags: plotting, graphics

Apologies for the noob question, I'm not very experienced with Mathematica, but I need it for a presentation.

What I would like is to make the x-y plane with both coordinates running from say, -5 to 5. Then I would like to add points manually, by entering their coordinates, while their coordinates are written next to the point. Something like this
https://gyazo.com/23ef6bb4f23739f8362fb1e3d666286c

Comment: `Graphics[{}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]` works as a starting canvas; you might then want to look into `LocatorPane[]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you an example.  If you are new to Mathematica, there will be many things to look up.  Just select a symbol name and hit F1 (or Command-Shift-F) to look it up in the documentation.  Once you understand it, you will be able to edit it to fit your needs.

```
points = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {10, 2}];

ListPlot[
 Labeled[#, StringForm["(``,``)", #[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ points,
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True,
 AxesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Arrowheads[0.05]],
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Gray],
 PlotRange -> 6 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]
]
```

[image]

You may want to wrap this expression with

```
Show[..., Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

to make the points render in front of the axes.

Comment: I will leave the message here.
Thanks for the quick help everyone!